# Why the strlen() function doesn't return the correct length for a hex string?

Tags: c, string-length

I have a hex string for example `\xF5\x17\x30\x91\x00\xA1\xC9\x00\xDF\xFF`, when trying to use `strlen()` function to get the length of that hex string it returns 4!

```
const char string_[] = { "\xF5\x17\x30\x91\x00\xA1\xC9\x00\xDF\xFF" };
unsigned int string_length = strlen(string_);
printf("%d", string_length); // the result: 4
```

**Is the `strlen()` function dealing with that hex as a string, or is something unclear to me?**

Comment: What is the value of the 5th element?

Comment: There are 4 bytes before null byte. All correct.

Comment: You confuse the C source code representation of data with the data at execution. In the code you posted, each group of 4 characters like `\xF5` or `\x17` is the source code representation of a single character. You can represent the same characters in octal as `"\0365\0027..."` (using 5 bytes for each character) but in the end, at runtime, they represent the same sequence of characters (the characters with the codes `245`, `23` a.s.o.). The fifth character in your string has the code `0`, therefore the length of the string is `4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For string functions in the C standard library, a character with value zero, also called a null character, marks the end of a string. Your string contains `\x00`, which designates a null character, so the string ends there. There are four non-null characters before it, so `strlen` returns four.

C 2018 7.1.1 1 says:

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character… The *length* of a string is the number of bytes preceding the null character…

C 2018 7.24.6.3 2 says:

> The `strlen` function computes the length of the string pointed to by `s` [its first argument].

You could compute the size of your array as `sizeof string_` (because it is an array of `char`) or `sizeof string_ / sizeof *string_` (to compute the number of elements regardless of type), but this will include a terminating null character because defining an array with `[]` and letting the length be computed from a string literal initializer includes the terminating null character of the string literal. You may need to hard-code the length of the array, possibly using `#define` to define a preprocessor macro, and use that length in the array definition and in other places where the length is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have **zero** at index `[4]`

```
string_[0] == 0xF5
string_[1] == 0x17
string_[2] == 0x30
string_[3] == 0x91
string_[4] == 0
...
```

`"\xf5"` puts `char` having **integer** value `0xf5` at position `[0]`

To see it as a string you need to escape the `\` character

```
const char string_[] = "\\xF5\\x17\\x30\\x91\\x00\\xA1\\xC9\\x00\\xDF\\xFF";
```

Answer (score 0):

At compile time, your "string" appears as consecutive hex values expressed in C syntax inside a pair of quotation marks.

`strlen()` is a **run time** function that scans through a series of bytes, looking for the first instance of a zero-value byte.

It's good to understand the difference between "compile time" and "run time".